# reindent shortcut in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, indentation

I tried to set the shortcut of `Reindent` in Sublime using the following approach:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+i"], "command": "reindent", "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
```

So, now I would expect the `Ctrl+Alt+i` to Reindent the selected code. I checked that the file with keybindings is saved by reopening it.

But when I select all and press `Ctrl+Alt+i` re indentation does not happen.

Also I checked that the keybinding does not appear on the `Reindent` button.

[image]

I tried to restart the editor, but neither did this help.

What can I do about the issue? Thank you.

Comment: Use `Tab` key. It's default key for Reindent.

Comment: @itsmysterybox, I would like to set my own keys. And why don\`t they right `Tab` next to Reindent if it is default, I am just curious. Thank you for the attempt to help. (y)

Comment: `Tab` to indent, `Shift+Tab` to reindent.